# Asynchronous parallel ForEach implemented using Task.Run

Tags: c#, error-handling, concurrency, async-await

I wrote a simple implementation of `aysnc parallel.ForEach( ... )`

All it really does is create a list of tasks and wait for them all to complete and aggregate the exceptions if any.

But to use `CancellationToken` I added `Task.Run` but I am worried that this is not the best way of stopping a task from running.

I could add *some* shortcuts in case the token cannot be cancelled, empty collections and so on.

But those are minor tweaks.

Anything else I could do to make `tasks.AddRange(source.Select(s => Task.Run(() => body(s), token)));` more efficient while allowing me to cancel running tasks.

```
public static async Task ForEach<T>(ICollection<T> source, Func<T, Task> body, CancellationToken token )
{
  // create the list of tasks we will be running
  var tasks = new List<Task>(source.Count);
  try
  {
    // and add them all at once.
    tasks.AddRange(source.Select(s => Task.Run(() => body(s), token)));

    // execute it all.
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray()).ConfigureAwait(false);

    // throw if we are done here.
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
  }
  catch
  {
    // find the error(s) that might have happened.
    var errors = tasks.Where(tt => tt.IsFaulted).Select(tu => tu.Exception).ToList();

    // we are back in our own thread
    if (errors.Count > 0)
    {
      throw new AggregateException(errors);
    }
  }
}
```

Any suggestions where I could improve performance and the creation of tasks?

Answer (score 2):

`Task.WhenAll` also accepts `Enumerable<Task>` as argument. So your lines with `tasks` can be simplified:

```
var tasks = source.Select(x => Task.Run(() => body(s), token));
try 
{
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
}
catch
{
    // find the error(s) that might have happened.
    var errors = tasks.Where(tt => tt.IsFaulted).Select(tu => tu.Exception).ToList();

    // we are back in our own thread
    if (errors.Count > 0)
    {
        throw new AggregateException(errors);
    }
}
```

If you end up throwing because of the line `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`, after all the tasks have completed (so none of the tasks themselves faulted), I think you end up swallowing the exception.

---

You provide the `CancellationToken` to `Task.Run`. The only thing this does is check whether the token has been cancelled *before* the tasks starts running. If you want to affect the task itself, you need to pass the token into the method `body` as well. Additionally, the implementation of `body` then needs to actually do something with the token (like checking whether it is cancelled), before cancelling will have any use.

So consider the following possible APIs:

```
Task ForEach<T>(ICollection<T> seq, Func<T, CancellationToken, Task> body, CancellationToken token)
```

or

```
Task ForEach<T>(ICollection<T> seq, Func<T, Task> body)
```

Not much in between will have much use, assuming it's the function `body` that you want to cancel.

For some additional reading, see [here](https://lbadri.wordpress.com/2016/10/04/cancellationtoken-with-task-run-and-wait/).

Comment: Thanks for the info on `Task.Run` I have to admit, I never knew that and thanks for the `Throw` that might never get caught. While I want the `body` to control the token I also want my `ForEach` to manage it, I might had a delay task and a `WhenAny`

Comment: Also, why did you move the `source.Select( ... )` out of the try/catch?

Comment: @FFMG multiple reasons: 1) It makes it more convenient, since we both need the collection of tasks in the `try`, as the `catch` block. Moving the declaration out, makes that possible. 2) There is no clear reason to put it in the `try` block. From the usage here,`try` is supposed to catch any exceptions the tasks might throw during their execution. If those tasks throw exceptions at some point during their execution, they will be caught by the created `Task` object (the objects in `tasks`), and stored until the result is accessed. In this example, the exceptions will be thrown by (cont.)

Comment: the statement that awaits the tasks: `await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);`, which is within the `try` block. 3) If the `source.Select` statement throws for some other reason than task failure or cancellation, like either `source` or `body` being `null`, you would also catch them in your `catch` block, which is not something you want, since the `catch` block currently would swallow those exceptions.